# Why can't I set DataLabel.Position to xlLabelPositionCustom?

Tags: vb.net, excel, charts, excel-2007

I am working with vb.net and excel 2007 to create some graphs for myself.  I wanted to set the datalabel positions to a custom value since the default above position (`xlLabelPositionAbove`) causes the labels to clash with error bars and the default option for a side (such as `xlLabelPositionRight`) may leave the label over another point or other errorbar.  Due to this, I wanted to set the label to a custom position where it is off to about a 45 degree angle to the top right (like right in the middle of where the default above and right positions would place it).

I tried doing this by adjusting `xlMySeries.Points(index).DataLabel.Top` and `xlMySeries.Points(index).DataLabel.Left` at first, however I ran into an undescriptive error leading me to believe I was not doing things correctly.  I then thought to try setting `xlMySeries.DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionCustom` and then adjusting top and left.  However, to my surprise, I could not even change `xlMySeries.DataLabels.Position` to `xlLabelPositionCustom`!

Whenever I try to adjust top, left, or the position to certain datalabel positions, I get  HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL), which I have generally found to mean "You are doing it wrong" in my experience so far with excel.  I cannot set the position member to custom, or anything other than just above, left, right, center (so not bestfit, custom, or any inside___ one)

Any idea why I cannot set the position property to what I need it or otherwise change the position of my datalabels?  I just need SOME way to adjust the positioning of my datalabels to a custom psoition (or position other than above, left, right, center, bottum).  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you get the existing values of these positions, so we have some context of where they are and to see what values you would like to reset them to?

Comment: I tried that: I can't see the value of top or left. But it is NOT that they aren't members of datalabel, the error is different then that (same as I mention above, "E_FAIL"). I even just tried assigning the value to an object type variable (because before I only tried with number types), and it still won't work.  I really have no idea what is going on with these datalabel members...

Comment: I just ran into the same problem.  Data labels were not behaving correctly in general.  I worked around it by creating `TextBox` shapes instead, and setting their values and moving them to the desired position.

Answer (score -1):

You can set positions only to whose which you can see on the Data Label properties window.